# Handle persian language in mysql when using 'LIKE'

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I used of codeigniter and want to search for a word Persian in Mysql database both word are the same but result is false because they do not match together.

How to handle persian language in mysql when using 'LIKE'?.(Of course, this is an example)

```
//$search_term = $this->input->post('search');
$search_term = 'فریدونکنار';
$this->db->select('final_record, province, province_num, city, city_num, CONCAT(province, " ، ", city) AS p_c', FALSE);

$this->db->like('province', $search_term);
$this->db->like('city', $search_term); //In this column as: فريدونكنار
$query = $this->db->get('city_name');
```

Comment: What is the character set/collation of your database and table?

Comment: utf8_general_ci was the first but now utf8_persian_ci.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://philsturgeon.uk/codeigniter/2009/08/17/UTF-8-support-for-CodeIgniter/

Comment: Of course, some words have this problem, not everyone.